# Is there a way to download a discord.js collection as a file and restore it if the bot goes down?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am developing an all-purpose discord bot in discord.js, and am using collections to store settings. The one problem with those collections is they get deleted every time the bot is restarted. What I want to know is if there is a way to save it to a file, and then restore it back to its original condition as if nothing ever happened if the bot shuts down. Is there any good way to do this? The only reason I want to know is because a lot of my bot is based off of the fact that the discord collection exists, and I don't want to rewrite the majority of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A discord.js collection is simply a javascript map with additional functionality. It should be pretty straight forward to store the collection as a json list into file.json as a list of lists.

```json
[
    [key, value],
    ...,
    [key, value]
]
```

It should be pretty straight forward to import that file into a collection.

```js
collection = new Discordjs.Collection{jsonFile};
```

I'll leave the implementation of storing the collection to you, remember that it's simply a javascript map with additional methods.

EDIT: [`Json.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) looks like a good way to convert a map into a json string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do something like this, at least what I know.
But what you can do is simply fetch everything you need after the bot started.

E.g. if you need to fetch all messages in all channels, do something like this:

```js
Promise.all(client.channels.cache.filter(c => c.isText()).map(async c => await c.messages.fetch())).then(() => {

 console.log("All messages fetched!");

});
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I want to write every single instance of the discord collection to a file, and then restore it later on.

Comment: I just figured out how to get all of them, now I need to set them

Comment: what do you mean by "instance of discord collection"?

Comment: (maybe edit your answer and tell us how you get them, maybe then we / I know what you mean)

Comment: He has his own collection of settings that are not fetched from discord api